# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when using the retina net library

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, python-2.x, retinanet

i am trying to load a model using the models.load_model() api but i keep getting this error.
I tried installing all the necessary keras and tensorflow library but it doesnot seem to work.

This is my current code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
import urllib
import os
from PIL import Image

from keras_retinanet import models
from keras_retinanet.utils.image import preprocess_image, resize_image
from keras_retinanet.utils.visualization import draw_box, draw_caption
from keras_retinanet.utils.colors import label_color

# https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/releases
# urllib.urlretrieve('https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/releases/download/0.5.1/resnet50_coco_best_v2.1.0.h5',
#     'pretrained_model.h5')
# retrieving the model
model = models.load_model('pretrained_model.h5')

class_names = [l.rstrip() for l in open('coco_categories.txt')]
print(class_name)
```

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Retinet_pretrained.py", line 18, in <module>
        model = models.load_model('pretrained_model.h5')
      File "/home/./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_retinanet/models/__init__.py", line 87, in load_model
        return keras.models.load_model(filepath, custom_objects=backbone(backbone_name).custom_objects)
      File "/home/./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_retinanet/models/__init__.py", line 57, in backbone
        from .resnet import ResNetBackbone as b
      File "/home/./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_retinanet/models/resnet.py", line 21, in <module>
        from . import retinanet
      File "/home/./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_retinanet/models/retinanet.py", line 19, in <module>
        from .. import layers
      File "/home/./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_retinanet/layers/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from ._misc import RegressBoxes, UpsampleLike, Anchors, ClipBoxes  # noqa: F401
      File "/home/./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_retinanet/layers/_misc.py", line 19, in <module>
        from .. import backend
      File "/home/./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_retinanet/backend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .backend import *  # noqa: F401,F403
      File "/home/./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_retinanet/backend/backend.py", line 100
        return tensorflow.map_fn(*args, **kwargs, fn_output_signature=sig)
                                                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you sure the keras version you're using supports Python2? Why aren't you using Python3?

Comment: The current implementation I am following uses python2, the keras works the issue comes when i use the retina net library

Comment: This is not an issue in keras but inside the keras_retinanet library. In any case you should not be using Python 2.

Comment: As shown, your code will not run any differently in Python2 than Python3. The syntax error you're getting is because Python2 doesn't allow keyword arguments after the **kwargs, which is only going to be solved by upgrading your Python version